# How to embed command shell in Visual Studio

Tags: windows, command-line, visual-studio-2005

I would like to be able to embed a command line interpreter inside a dockable window in Visual Studio. Is there any nice way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the [VS Command shell](http://www.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?ProjectName=VSCmdShell) project

Comment: This tool supports Visual Studio 2005 and 2008.  Does anyone know of such a tool that supports 2010 or later?  I searched and didn't find one.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [Open Command Line](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.OpenCommandLine) by Mads Kristensen. **note** it doesn't really "embed" the shell in VS, rather it adds a keyboard shortcut to open the shell at the project directory

it supports bash, powershell, git bash, ...etc

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio click Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Manager Console

It embeds a cmd prompt with everything on your %PATH% you'd expect.